# Execute code in form load pyside and python

Tags: python, forms, pyqt, pyside

when I add code to be executed in **init** method of the form it executes before form shown, and I want to execute my code after form displayed to user
I tried to override show() and showEvent() methods but still same behavior

from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from Ui_frmGreeting import Ui_frmGreeting

```
class frmGreeting(QDialog, Ui_frmGreeting):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        QMessageBox.information(self, 'Registeration done', 'You have registered successfully')
```

the message appears before form displayed and I want to show it after form displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your setupUI, have you tried doing a self.show()?